# GWTP ResourceDelegate response undefined

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-gin

I'm trying to get the response from a REST service from my GWTP presenter. My securityDelegate trigger onSuccess method but the UserDTO seems to be empty. The network tool show me the request with HTTP code 200 and the response with current user. For some reason the UserDTO seems to be empty.

The LOGGER show me

CLASS:xx.xxxx.xxx.web.shared.dto.UserDTO@1f

Name:undefined

```
    //LoginPresenter.java
    securityDelegate.withCallback(new AsyncCallback<UserDTO>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Window.alert("fail");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UserDTO user) {
            LOGGER.info("CLASS:"+user.toString());
            LOGGER.info("Name:"+user.getName());
        }
    }).authenticate(username,password);

    //SecurityResource.java
    @Path("/security")
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public interface SecurityResource {

        @POST
        @Path ("/authenticate")
        RestAction<UserDTO> authenticate(@HeaderParam ("username") String username,@HeaderParam("password") String password);
    }

    //SecurityResourceImpl.java
    @Path ("/security")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class SecurityResourceImpl {

        @EJB
        private SecurityBean securityBean;

        @POST
        @Path("/authenticate")
        @Override
        public Response authenticate(@HeaderParam ("username")
    String username, @HeaderParam("password") String password){

        User currentUser = securityBean.find(username,password);
        return Response.ok().entity(new UserDTO(currentUser)).build();
      }
}

    //UserDTO.java
    public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

        private String name;

        public UserDTO(){
        }

        public UserDTO(User user){...}
        //getters/setters
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I forgot to define the setters! I defined UserDTO as builder pattern.